# Passing parameters through action-state for bean method

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, spring-webflow

I have a simple question. I have myView.xhtml, my-flow.xml and myBean.java.

In myView.xhtml I have

```
<h:outputText value="otherBean.value"/>
<h:commandLink action="myAction"/>
```

In my-flow.xml I have (let's suppose transition from myAction to MyAction in the view-state)

```
<action-state id="MyAction"> 
  <evaluate expression="myBean.validate()"/>
  <transition on="success" to="anywhere"/>
</action-state>
```

And in myBean.java, I have a method

```
public Event validate() {
  ...
  return success();
}
```

Now, if I wanted to pass a value of outputText to the validate method, when commandLink is pressed, what would be the correct syntax? Do I have to add f:param to my commandLink and grab that param from context? Or can I do something like

```
public Event validate(Object myParam){
...
  return success();
}
```

where myParam would be passed from myView.xhtml and equal to otherBean.value, if so how to modify myView and my-flow? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You know JSF and Spring MVC cannot reside in the same house. All other assumptions will then severely be broken.

Comment: You are probably right, by adding these tags I meant jsf + spring integration

Comment: That's Spring Webflow, not Spring MVC.